# Securing GoDaddy Shared Hosting Account Hosting Multiple Sites

Tags: security, godaddy, shared-hosting

How secure is it having multiple sites on same godaddy shared hosting account?

1. If I give client their own ftp access to their directory - theoretically they can upload any php script they want and if they are adventurous/unknowingly install malicious script which can then modify/delete files across all sites. I wrote a sample script to test this which I placed in hosting/testsite/www/test.php and I managed to delete files in root dir(I didn't yet check if I could go back down to other child dirs).
2. Even if I wouldn't give them ftp access but say they have Wordpress with access to Admin Panel - they could always upload malicious theme/plugin with the same effect!
3. Please add other loopholes that are caused by hosting multiple sites

So is there a way of blocking these loopholes (and others). Am I able to setup multiple users with each one only having permission to read/write their own site and say giving read only access to necesssarry root dirs (e.g. frameworks/cms's). Remember I am specifically asking about shared hosting plans where probably there are more limitations. I have  SSH setup but if possible what commands would I need(I couldn't find anything in web interface).

Or this is the limit and I can only host multiple sites(with FTP/Wordpress standard Admin Interface) for clients that I trust that will not play around?

Answer (score 1):

If all your clients are on the same account, then they will be able to access each other's data. This is obviously a **very bad idea**.

Instead of using a single account, use a [reseller account](http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/reseller-hosting.aspx); this will let you give each client an individual account of their own; you can also bill them separately.

Comment: But is there anyway to use linux commands such us chmod/chroot etc. to set up different users so that they can't access each others files?